# FINDSTR in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, find, command-prompt, findstr

I am trying to generate a file with all of the rows from an input file containing a certain string using the `FINDSTR` commanand in `cmd.exe`. My command below does not produce any results, whereas the `FIND` command (also below) shows that there are 182,688 rows containing the string I'm looking for...

**FIND command:**

```
FIND /c "searchstring" c:\Users\karl\Desktop\Report.csv
```

gives the following:

```
---------- C:\USERS\KARL\DESKTOP\REPORT.CSV: 182688
```

**FINDSTR command:**

```
findstr /i /c:"searchstring" c:\Users\karl\Desktop\Report.csv > results.out
```

gives me a blank file called results.out.

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is your `searchstring`?  The most likely culprit as I see it now is that the behavior of your search string is not what you intend in your `findstr` command; that what you intend as a literal string is being interpreted as regexp notation with unintended special meaning.

Comment: @rojo - I agree, the search string is probably not getting interpreted as desired. But it can't be a regex issue because the `/c` option defaults to a literal search unless the `/r` option is added.

Comment: @dbenham - so for instance `findstr /i /c:"*abcd*"` would search for literal (asterisk)abcd(asterisk), rather than a string containing `abcd`?  That clears up some long-time confusion.  Up until now I've simply avoided using spaces in my expressions so I didn't have to use the `/c` switch with `findstr`.  Huh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINDSTR has many undocumented "features" that could be tripping you up. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053)

You have not told us what your search string is, so I can't be sure. But your problem is probably related to one or more of the following:

- Special rules for escaping `"` and `\` within literal search strings
- Many extended ASCII characters do not find themselves when used in command line search strings.
- FINDSTR cannot search unicode files. I am told that FIND can search unicode files.

Comment: My string did indeed contain characters that could not be found. I ended up using MS Access to perform the required query. Many Thanks @dbenham

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. the /n gives a line number:

`findstr /i /n "\<searchstring\>" c:\Users\karl\Desktop\Report.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Find some string inside all text files in current directory example:

```
cls & for %i in (*.txt) do find /i "search text" < "%i" && (echo : %i & echo -)
```

**What you are missing is the redirector**; if your last search file fails search, your code deletes all content of the result file. Replace with append redirector, eg, to store results of search in a file:

```
for %i in (*.txt) do (find /i "giff" < "%i" && (echo : %i & echo -)) >> results.txt
```

Tested in Win 10