# How can I get the '…' character into a findstr in cmd?

Tags: command-line, cmd, special-characters, findstr

I'm trying to search for a special character using the CMD command:

```
findstr /s /i <special_character> *.*
```

The character I want to search for is `…`

That is, three dots all compressed into a single character.

How can I do this?

Comment: this char is called [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) and is an [Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm). Sorry, but `findst` [can't handle that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15280875/2152082).

Comment: Is there any other way to search for it? Or for the hex code itself?

Comment: in Unicode each character is coded into two bytes. For the ellipsis, it's `0x20 0x26`  which luckily happens to be two ASCII printable characters (space and `&`, so searching with `find " &` or `findstr /c:" &` should do. Might give false positives when used on an ASCII file.

Comment: Do you mean find " &"? I'm not sure why you have open quotes without closing.

Comment: yes, of course. Was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the character encoding of the text file is Microsoft Windows proprietary codepage 1252 (English and Western Europe), then you can use `FINDSTR.EXE`.

The ellipsis in codepage 1252 is at 0x85. To enter the character at the command line using codepage 437, you would hold down the Alt key while entering the decimal value of 0x85. That decimal value is 133.

Enter the following text into Notepad by either copy and paste or holding down the Alt key while entering on the numeric keypad 0133. Save this as `myscript.bat`.

```
findstr /L "…" myfile.txt
```

From a `cmd` shell, enter `TYPE myscript.bat`. It will appear as shown below. This is because 133 in codepage 1252 is the HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS character, but in codepage 437 it is a LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE.

```
findstr /L "à" myfile.txt
```

Use the `chcp` command to see the codepage currently used in the `cmd` shell.

When `myscript.bat` is run from the `cmd` shell, the character at codepoint 0x85 will appear as LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE because it is in codepage 437.

Comment: chcp showed 437, but when I hold alt and type '133' nothing happens.

Comment: That is, it just enters as the literal number 133

Comment: Open Notepad and hold down the Alt key and enter 133 on the keypad.

Comment: When I did it in notepad, as soon as I hit alt +1, I heard the windows 'bell' error sound, and nothing happened. The following 3s had the same effect.

Comment: Copy and paste ` findstr /L "à" elli.txt` into Notepad.

Comment: Change` the file name from `elli.txt` to the one you want to search. Save this as a .

Comment: But that's not the ellipse character, it's an à

Comment: I have to get to a real machine to answer. A little later.

Comment: I tried findstr /s /i "…" *.* from a .bat and it didn't work. It was hitting lines that did not contain the character.